# Paypal sandbox return always waiting status after change currency

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I'm working to integrate Paypal IPN support to my website based on codeigniter.
I have make many test before yesterday using Paypal Sandbox without problem.
However from yesterday, after change DOLLAR to EURO on my website, when I try to make test, paypal return always waiting status on my IPN script. 
I don't understand why, on Paypal Sandbox I get messages about payment complete.
The account used for make the test have set country as Italy.

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting your IPNs just fine, right?  It's just that the payment_status is "waiting"?

It could be that the receiver account has to accept the payment because its in a different currency.  If you login as the buyer, you may see that, and then when you accept them you should see new IPNs for the same transaction with a new payment status.

Comment: Where can I change currency? I cannot found this settings in PayPal sandbox.

Comment: See docs for the payment acceptance stuff at:https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_receive-outside